# Procedure or function expects parameter '@' which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2019, visual

Tengo un error a la hora de llamar mis procedimientos en vs, estoy tratando de insertar_alumnos. Mis procedimientos son los siguientes: Aquí tengo el nombre, tipo de usuarios y ID ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insertar_alumnos] en sQL

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Insertar_alumnos]    Script Date: 20/05/2022 10:13:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Insertar_alumnos]
@Apellido_Paterno varchar(50),
           @Apellido_Materno varchar(50),
           @Nombres varchar(50),
           @Fecha_de_nacimiento varchar(50),
           @Nro_de_documento varchar(50),
           @Estado_civil varchar(50),
          @Sexo varchar(50),
           @Nacionalidad varchar(50),
           @Telefono varchar(50),
           @Departamento varchar(50),
           @Provincia varchar(50),
           @Distrito varchar(50),
          @Direccion varchar(50),
           @Departamento2 varchar(50),
           @Provincia2 varchar(50),
           @Distrito2 varchar(50),
           @Telefono1 varchar(50),
           @Telefono2 varchar(50),
           @Correo varchar(50),
           @Profesion varchar(50),
          @Local_studio varchar(50),
           @Fecha_de_Matricula varchar(50),
           @Fecha_de_Inicio varchar(50),
           @Codigo varchar(50),
           @Estado as int
as
IF EXISTS(sELECT Nro_de_documento From Alumnos  WHERE Nro_de_documento= @Nro_de_documento)
RAISERROR('Ya existe un Alumno con ese Numero de Documento, POR FAVOR INGRESE DE NUEVO',16,1)
ELSE
INSERT INTO Alumnos
values(
  @Apellido_Paterno ,
           @Apellido_Materno,
           @Nombres,
           @Fecha_de_nacimiento,
           @Nro_de_documento,
           @Estado_civil,
           @Sexo,
           @Nacionalidad,
           @Telefono,
           @Departamento,
           @Provincia,
           @Distrito,
           @Direccion,
           @Departamento2,
           @Provincia2,
           @Distrito2,
           @Telefono1,
           @Telefono2,
           @Correo,
           @Profesion,
           @Local_studio,
           @Fecha_de_Matricula,
           @Fecha_de_Inicio,
           @Codigo,
           @Estado )
```

Codigo del Formulario Alumnos en visual Basic .NET
Asi hice mi procedimiento en visualbasic.NET la funcion insertar_alumnos y tampoco me funciona la funcion editar_alumnos me bota el mismo error. Al parecer es por la variable @Apellido_Materno que no lo identifica. Pero no encuentro donde esta el error.Ayudenme por favor
Alumnos_form.vb

```
Public Class Alumnos_form
    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub



    Private Sub Guardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guardar.Click
        Try
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            abrir()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Insertar_alumnos", conexion)
            cmd.CommandType = 4
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido_Paterno", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apelllido_Materno", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombres", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha_de_nacimiento", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nro_de_documento", txtdocumento.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado_civil", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexo", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nacionalidad", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departamento", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provincia", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distrito", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departamento2", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provincia2", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distrito2", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono1", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono2", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profesion", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Local_studio", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha_de_Matricula", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha_de_inicio", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cerrar()
            MOSTRAR()
            Panel4.Visible = False

        Catch ex As Exception : MsgBox(ex.Message)


        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub GuardarCambiosToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GuardarCambiosToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Try
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            abrir()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("editar_ALUMNO", conexion)
            cmd.CommandType = 4
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido_Paterno", txtapellidoPaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apelllido_Materno", txtapellidoMaterno.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombres", txtnombre.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nro_de_documento", txtdocumento.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idalumno", id_alumno)



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cerrar()
            MOSTRAR()
            Panel4.Visible = False

        Catch ex As Exception : MsgBox(ex.Message)


        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtdocumento_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtdocumento.TextChanged

    End Sub
    Sub MOSTRAR()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        Try
            abrir()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("mostrar_alumnos", conexion)
            da.Fill(dt)
            dataListado.DataSource = dt
            cerrar()
            Multilinea(dataListado)
            dataListado.Columns(1).Visible = False

        Catch ex As Exception : MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)


        End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub Alumnos_form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MOSTRAR()
        Panel4.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click
        Panel4.Visible = True
        txtapellidoMaterno.Clear()
        txtapellidoPaterno.Clear()
        txtnombre.Clear()
        txtdocumento.Clear()
        Guardar.Visible = True
        GuardarCambiosToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False






    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Panel4.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub dataListado_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataListado.CellContentClick

    End Sub
    Dim id_alumno As Integer
    Private Sub dataListado_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataListado.CellDoubleClick
        Try
            Panel4.Visible = True
            id_alumno = dataListado.SelectedCells.Item(1).Value
            txtapellidoPaterno.Text = dataListado.SelectedCells.Item(2).Value
            txtapellidoMaterno.Text = dataListado.SelectedCells.Item(3).Value
            txtnombre.Text = dataListado.SelectedCells.Item(4).Value
            txtdocumento.Text = dataListado.SelectedCells.Item(5).Value
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta agregar los nombres de cada columna de tu tabla Alumnos (columname1, columnname2, etc) values(@1, @2, @3, etc ) y no solo los parametros en el insert.

Comment: Asegurate que tu texbox no llegue vacio, validalos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pusiste "Apelllido_Materno" con 3 l , no deberia ir con 2?:

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ape**lll**ido_Materno",...

Comment: Gracias. Eso era justo lo que estaba ocasionando el problema. Gracias de verdad. Ya lo solucioné